# letters with accents gone

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings

Today I used Dropbox to transfer all my tex-files from my computer to my new Laptop (same OS). In all the tex-files, my letters with accents (é, è, à, etc.) are gone and I get the error "Package imputent Error: Unicode character (U+008E) not set up for use with LaTeX."

In my preamble I used:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
```

I can fix it by deleting all the words containing such a letter an rewriting them. But maybe there is something else I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure that you have saved the files in utf8 and not latin1 (iso-8859-1)

Comment: Is the error on U+008E reported on the character Ž ?

Comment: Tanks. Indeed, the files have not all been saved in utf8. Porblem solved!

Answer (score 2):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

declares to latex that all the files are in UTF-8 (actually for recent versions of LaTeX that is the default anyway so this declaration isn't needed)

Depending on how files are copied or created it may be that the files get stored in a legacy encoding such as iso-8859-1 (latin1) or a windows code page such as cp1251 (Cyrillic) or 1252 (Western European). In such a case LaTeX can not give a global "the file is in the wrong encoding" error it just tries to interpret the bytes in the file as UTF-8 and so usually reports a fairly low level error at the first character that produces bytes incompatible with UTF-8, as you show.

Most text editors should give the option of re-saving the file in UTF-8.